# Replace item in wxPython GridSizer

Tags: python, wxpython, sizer

I have a `wx.Frame` with a `wx.GridSizer`. This grid contains several custom `wx.Panel`. I need to swap the content of two cells of my grid. I tried several solutions using `Detach`, `GetItem`, and `Insert` methods without success.

For example suppose I have a 3x3 grid with 8 elements (my custom panels) from 0 to 7. In this case the last cell of the grid is empty. I want to move the last item (grid[7]) in the last cell (grid[8]).

How can I do? And what are the differences if the last the last cell is not empty?

Answer (score 2):

'panelInGrid7' in the following is the instance of your panel which is in grid[7], in gridBagSizer positions this would be in (2, 1)

```
sizer.Detach(panelInGrid7)
sizer.Add(panelInGrid7, (2,3))
```

If (2, 3) is not empty you would need to detach that item too and then add it to where you want it.